# Assign Specific key to Array Elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows :-

```
$alldatesandtimes = ["2016-10-04 00:00:01","2016-10-04 23:59:59","2016-10-05 00:00:01","2016-10-05 23:59:59","2016-10-06 00:00:01","2016-10-06 23:59:59"]
```

I want to assign datein as the index of first element and dateout to 2nd element. Then datein as the index of 3rd element and dateout to 4th element and so on and so forth to all the remaining elements.

so first index shall be datein and 2nd index shall be dateout then keep on upto the last element.

I have following code :-

```
$keys = array();
$result = array();
for($j=0; $j<((sizeof($alldatesandtimes))/2); $j++)
{
  $keys[] = "datein";
  $keys[] = "dateout";
}//end for loop

for($i = 0; $i< sizeof($alldatesandtimes); $i++)
{
  $result[][$keys[$i]] =$alldatesandtimes[$i];
}
```

it returns the following array :-

```
$result = Array ( [0] => Array ( [datein] => 2016-10-04 00:00:01 ) [1] => Array ( [dateout] => 2016-10-04 23:59:59 ) [2] => Array ( [datein] => 2016-10-05 00:00:01 ) [3] => Array ( [dateout] => 2016-10-05 23:59:59 ) [4] => Array ( [datein] => 2016-10-06 00:00:01 ) [5] => Array ( [dateout] => 2016-10-06 23:59:59 ) )
```

but i want

```
$result = ['datein' => '2016-10-04 00:00:01', 'dateout' => '2016-10-04 23:59:59', 'datein' => '2016-10-05 00:00:01', .....
```

Kindly help me?

Comment: impossible indexes have to be unique.

Comment: just add your keys to the original array

Comment: So I assumed from `$result[][$keys[$i]]` that you wanted multidimensional, if not then see @RobertParham comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can chunk it into pairs and then combine the value pairs with the key pair:

```
foreach(array_chunk($alldatesandtimes, 2) as $pair) {
    $result[] = array_combine(['datein', 'dateout'], $pair);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the array with incrementing the $i variable by two ( $i+2). This way you all get every second element. after that assign a new array to another array as follows

```
$result[]=array("datein"=>$arr[$i], "dateout" => $arr[$i+1]);
```

Comment: if you do it like that assuming $i is only incremented by one each loop, the enddate will always be the startdate for the next array.

Comment: I explicitly mentioned that the loop must increment $i+2 instead of $i++

Comment: i didn't see that, but [it would have been easier and more readable if you had just added the loop](https://3v4l.org/mOKIJ) to the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Not nearly as fancy as abra's answer but...

```
$newDates = array();
$dateHolder = array();
foreach($alldatesandtimes as $k=>$v){
    $key = $k%2===0 ? "dateIn" : "dateOut";
    $newDates[$key] = $v;
    if(count($newDates)===2){
        $dateHolder[] = $newDates;
        $newDates = array();
    }
}
$alldatesandtimes = $dateHolder;
```

https://3v4l.org/BCoYd